# setMaxResult(0) returning an empty List in hibernate 5.2.6+ but which was not the case in prior versions

Tags: java, hibernate-5.x

I am migrating the hibernate version from `5.0.12.Final` to `5.4.28.Final` and I had performed some obvious straightforward deprecated changes like changing `org.hibernate.Query` to `org.hibernate.query.Query`, but encountered the following breaking change.

**Example code Snippet**

```
Query query = this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("fetchPhotos");
query.setFirstResult(firstResult);
query.setMaxResults(limit);
return query.list();
```

Before the version migration even we set `setMaxResults` value as `zero` which was considered as  **`no limits`**, but the latest hibernate changes returning `Collections#emptyList` immediately whenever it satisfies the condition `maxResults==0`. Subsequent analysis found that the [change](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/commit/318473e59caddafa8f38b672f8d38ea6911c696c) is because of [hibernate ticket](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11278), also found the library level [test case](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/a514460bb9b686d1e4e9aad86acd5eb86ca15bcb/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/criteria/limitexpression/LimitExpressionTest.java#L63) to assert the behavior. Though `Query.setMaxResults(0)` seems illogical, the latest change enforcing us to have a condition similar to below

```
if(limit > 0){
   query.setMaxResults(limit);
}
```

The real problem is we have used `query.setMaxResults(limit)` snippet in umpteen places in our entire code base and changing all the code occurrences seems time-consuming. **Is there any workaround exist** to keep the backward compatibility behavior such as `setMaxResults(0)` == **`no limits`**